# Ctags generate latest version gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, ctags

I use [vim-rails](http://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) and `ctags` for navigate of methods. For it I run `ctags -R *` in `/home/***/.rvm/gems/ruby***/gems`. But in this directory was many folders for one gems just different versions(for example `activerecord` v. `3.0.7/3.1.3/3.2.2/3.2.3`). And when I try go to(`ctrl+]`) method I get to old version. How I can run ctags only with latest gems version?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make bundler show the locations for the gems in the gemfile with

```
bundle show --paths
```

If you pipe this list into ctags I think you will have what you need.

```
bundle show --paths | xargs ctags -R
```

edit:
Summarized in this blogpost: 
http://heim.no/VIM/2012/04/19/generate-ctags-for-all-bundled-gems-in-a-ruby-project/

Comment: Andreas, thanks for the info. I posted this question on your blog a few months ago but haven't gotten around it: I've found a problem in that, I can only go to the tags when I'm originating from a file in my project.  Once I'm in a file that is contained in one of the gems I'm using, I can't follow any of the methods called in that file to it's method definition.  I believe it's because it doesn't know how to find the ctags file relative to the file I'm currently browsing. Have you had any problems like I'm seeing?

Comment: Tony, seems like I actually have to check this out a bit and post an update (as I said a couple of months ago) :)

Comment: This is great. But it generates ctags only for gems. How do i make it generate for both gems and current project?

Comment: @Sathish I posted answer to this below

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add tags for your project along with the gemfile tags you can use `-a` option to append so you can just do:

```
ctags -R -f .tags && bundle show --paths | xargs ctags -R -a -f .tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Work-around: I'm not sure of a direct method, but you always have the option of editing the "tags" file manually, search/replace for all older gems versions and delete them or maybe delete all gems related sections and later on you can append to the tags file using [ctags -a *3.2.3*]

Comment: Yes, I know. But `tags` file has more than 63000 rows and editing manually is not good idea. And remove all gems expect for the latest version is not good idea too, because I may need later older gems version.
My first question is not correct. How I can use gems version which used in `Gemfile`?